# Error creating trigger in Oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm a student learning SQL in Oracle.  I'm creating a trigger and within the trigger I'm calling a procedure update_price_history(item_id, NEW.price).

This is the statement I did,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upd_hist_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF price ON Item
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 IF :NEW.price != price THEN
 update_price_history(item_id, NEW.price)
 END IF;
END;
```

I thought I had everything correct but I'm getting an error message:
Error(3,2): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: := . ( % ; The symbol ";" was substituted for "END" to continue.

I've been trying to figure out what I'm getting wrong and I'm not seeing what it is.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the semicolon at the end

```
...
update_price_history(item_id, :NEW.price);
...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I see the missed : and ; clearly now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upd_hist_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF price ON Item
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
 item_id number;
BEGIN
 IF :NEW.price != price THEN
 update_price_history(item_id, :NEW.price);
 END IF;
END;
```

you forgot `:` in front of `new` and a semicolon `;` after procedure. By the way, i can't see any variable definition of `item_id`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I thought that since item_id was a variable of item, I didn't have to declare it in the trigger.  It's funny how you can stare at something for so long that you can't see the error right in front of your face.

Comment: @RHillman you're welcome, we all human beings, sometimes hard to see something ;)